# Find and replace function for R

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that can modify a dataframe to find and replace a specific word or character with another?

If I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
|         Full Path        |    File   |
|:------------------------:|:---------:|
| C:/Path/to/the/file1.ext | file1.ext |
| C:/Path/to/the/file2.ext | file2.ext |
| C:/Path/to/the/file3.ext | file3.ext |
| C:/Path/to/the/file4.ext | file4.ext |
```

I'd like to modify it to look like this

```
|         Full Path        |    File   |
|:------------------------:|:---------:|
| C:\Path\to\the\file1.ext | file1.ext |
| C:\Path/to\the\file2.ext | file2.ext |
| C:\Path/to\the\file3.ext | file3.ext |
| C:\Path/to\the\file4.ext | file4.ext |
```

Comment: `gsub` and `sub` replace stuff in strings, `sub("Path/", "Path\", fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting that comment.  It won't work

Comment: @bunk So I could use gsub("/", "\", fixed=TRUE) and it would perfectly swap those out?

Comment: @David sry, specifically you would do, `tst <- "C:/Path/to/the/file1.ext"; gsub("/", "\\", tst, fixed=TRUE)`, notice you need the "\\" to escape the character

Comment: @bunk wouldn't you need to have a tst for each file? (1-4)? What if the dataframe isn't always the same number of entries?

Comment: @David honestly i cant tell what you are trying to do, but those functions should help

Comment: @bunk I thought I made it fairly clear in the question. I'm trying to take the 1st dataframe and turn it into the 2nd dataframe

Comment: @bunk - "this comment adds something useful to the post" is the meaning of comment voting.

Comment: @RichardScriven LOL if you say so

Comment: I don't say so, Stack Overflow says so

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(rep("this/and/that",5),rep("the other",5)),ncol=2))
df
             X1        X2
1 this/and/that the other
2 this/and/that the other
3 this/and/that the other
4 this/and/that the other
5 this/and/that the other

data.frame(apply((df),MARGIN = 2,function(x){gsub("/","\\",x,fixed = TRUE)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

               X1        X2
1 this\\and\\that the other
2 this\\and\\that the other
3 this\\and\\that the other
4 this\\and\\that the other
5 this\\and\\that the other
```

Comment: Why not just operate on the single column? `df$X1 <-  gsub("/", "\\", df$X1, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: the question was "modify a data frame" not a column

Comment: That is modifying a column inside a data frame.  It just happens to be a single column so we don't have to loop it.

Comment: correct... but still, the question was to "modify a data frame", not a data frame column

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  But good luck if the other columns contain numeric data.  You've just converted the entire thing to factor columns

Comment: you can use `data.frame(t(apply((df),MARGIN = 1,function(x){gsub("/","\\",x,fixed = TRUE)})),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` if you want to avoid factors, and this was written for human speed of writing, not computer speed of processing. Keep in mind this is a list of file names, 1 extra millisecond won't matter

Comment: I agree that there's a better solution, but how is lapply specifically any different/better than this...?

Comment: I see double backslashes in your result. Don't you want singles there?

Comment: I edited my answer to go over columns instead of going over rows and `t()`ing, but I also `microbenchmark`ed `as.data.frame((lapply((df),function(x){gsub("/","\\",x,fixed = TRUE)})),stringsasfactors=TRUE)` and it was actually about 10% slower. making it data.frame instead of as.data.frame made it an addtional 33% slower. but again all this is a moot point, if you have a speedy solution please answer this. the apply way took me less than a minute to write which is why I went with it

Comment: @hedgedandlevered - I'm not trying to  get on your case, but I just don't see any reason to loop when OP just wants to change the first column.  Like I said in my first comment, I think `df$X1 <- gsub("/", "\\", df$X1, fixed = TRUE)` is the best way to go here.

Comment: yes, that is correct for one column, as I agreed with you earlier

Comment: @RichardScriven Any idea why if I modify the dataframe `df` like this and then later call df$X1 that I get the/file.ext and not the\file.ext? Even when the dataframe shows as correctly being modified?

Comment: @David - did you assign the result?  Like `newdf <- as.data.frame(...)`  This will create the new modified data frame which you can then call `newdf$X1` and it should be fine

Comment: @RichardScriven I used `df$X1 <- gsub("/", "\\", df$X1, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @David - I'm not sure.  I just tried it and it worked fine on my end.  Maybe write up a new question to show what is happening